# Alternative to Maplesoft

Tags: maple

I want to use MapleSoft for small project (few days) and want don't to buy it. Since, it doesn't provide any free trial period, I am looking for some alternative. I am planning to use Maple to solve some sequence and series that it seems solves seamlessly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems, for example: SAGE, Maximia and others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/) has a free trial that you could take a look at (and *in my opinion* is the most powerful CAS)
- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is also pretty good, but may be more difficult to get work on all platforms
- Personally, I think the easiest one to use for quick stuff is [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html); it has virtually no learning curve if you already know Python.

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550/best-open-source-mathematica-equivalent).